# Difference atexit() and at_quick_exit()

Tags: c++, c++11, exit

What is the difference between `atexit()` and `at_quick_exit()`?
Does every function that we register at atexit() must be also registered at at_quick_exit()?
For example the Phoenix-Singleton custom functions or something else.

Comment: Downvoted; shows no research effort. Looking this up online is trivial.

Comment: So easy to find the answer on internet: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/at_quick_exit and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit, finally: The registered functions will not be called on normal program termination. If a function need to be called in that case, std::atexit must be used.

Answer (score 2):

Well, from [at_quick_exit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/at_quick_exit):

`Registers the function pointed to by func to be called on quick program termination (via std::quick_exit).
...
The registered functions will not be called on normal program termination. If a function need to be called in that case, std::atexit must be used.`

Functions registerd on `atexit()` are called on `exit()`. Functions registered with `at_quick_exit()` are called on `quick_exit()`.
The other difference is that `at_quick_exit()` is available from C++11 and is not available in C.

Comment: `at_quick_exit` is available in C since C11